# React-tools: app.jsx changed; rebuilding... never ends

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react.js, and I use npm have react-tools installed.
But after I type the command: jsx --watch src/ build/ and I did some changes to my jsx file.
The console logs:

```
app.jsx changed; rebuilding...
[]
```

It never ends.

Did someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah I had the same thing. I managed to get it working by explicitly setting jsx as the file extension when resolving module identifiers

```
jsx -w -x jsx src/ build/
```